# How to Use the Find Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently Written some code to take an input from a userform text box and search for it in my database. If found I would like it to return the value and insert it into cell A1149; I have written the below code but it gives me error #424 "Object Required". I am very new to VBA so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CMDSearch_Click()

     Dim pesquisa As Range

     Set pesquisa = Worksheets("Petrobras").Activate.Range("$W:$W") _
         .Find(What:=Opp_Num_Search.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Activate

     Worksheets("Petrobras").Range(A1149).Value = pesquisa.Value

     UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: That means the `Find` is not successful.

Comment: Why the `activate`? That is a method which lacks a return value. It doesn't return a range object.

Comment: Get rid of both `Activate`s and check that `pesquisa is not nothing` before assigning its value to something.

Answer (score 2):

`Range.Activate` doesn't return anything, it's like a `Sub` procedure:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    ' does something...
End Sub
```

If you did `Set foo = DoSomething.Something`, you'd get the same error: an object is required, otherwise that `.Something` member call is illegal (except now the error would be at compile-time and not run-time, because of how binding works).

> ```
> Set pesquisa = Worksheets("Petrobras").Activate...
> ```

You don't want to `Activate` any sheets.

Part of the problem is the implicit late-binding going on: `Worksheets` returns an `Object`, so everything you wrote after that, all these chained member calls, can only be resolved at run-time.

Make it early-bound, by declaring an explicit `Worksheet` variable:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("Petrobras")
```

Now if you want to activate it, you can do `sheet.Activate` (but you don't need to). And if you want to get a `Range` from that worksheet, you can make a `.Range` member call, *and the IDE will now help you do it*:

```
Dim result As Range
Set result = sheet.Range("$W:$W").Find(...)
```

**NEVER** chain any member calls to what `Range.Find` returns. If the search turned up a result, you have a `Range` object. If it didn't, you have `Nothing` - and any member call made against `Nothing` will always raise run-time error 91.

Validate the search result first:

```
If result Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find '" & Opp_Num_Search.Value & "' in column W."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Or:

```
If Not result Is Nothing Then
    sheet.Range("A1149").Value = result.Value
End If
```

Note that `A1149` is a *string literal* representing a cell address, and as such it must be surrounded with double quotes (`"`). If it's not in double quotes and it looks like a valid variable name, VBA will treat it as ..a variable... and that will cause yet another error (1004), because `Range` will be rather unhappy to work with a `Variant/Empty` value.

To prevent VBA from "declaring" on-the-fly variables with a typo (and causing hard-to-find bugs), make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the very top of every module in your project.

One last thing:

> ```
>  UserForm1.Hide
> ```

This hides *the default instance* of `UserForm1`, which may or may not be the current object / instance that's shown - and the form itself has no way to know how it was shown:

```
UserForm1.Show '<~ shows the default instance
```

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show '<~ shows a new (non-default) instance
End With
```

For this reason, you should avoid referring to the default instance in a form's code-behind. Use `Me` instead:

```
Me.Hide
```

That way you're referring to *whatever instance of the form is currently shown*, whether that's the default instance or not. See [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for more information, tips, pitfalls and common mistakes involving userforms.

Note that [Rubberduck has quite a few inspections](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) that can identify and warn you about (and often, automatically fix) most of these problems. Rubberduck is a free and open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage.

Comment: Perfectly explained. I have often thought about explaining these things but am too lazy to type all of this. I will mark it as fav and just point to this from here on in :)

Comment: Hello Mathieu i would like to thank your for your answer as it was very easy to read and understand, However i am having a bit of trouble using the Find Function

Comment: @AXL see [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), with particular important emphasis on the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#remarks). Other than that, I'd need a much clearer description of what the problem is.